# JavaScript Show / Hide (toggle) function toggling classes but not working at the frontEnd

Tags: javascript, wordpress

My goal is to be able to show / hide excerpt of the content.
This is a wordpress site so posts are generated hence giving a button a unique ID is not an option. It must be working for all added posts in the future too.

The excerpt should be first hidden and shown once the button is clicked.

Current code adds and removes .excerpt class, however, the excerpt is not showing.

HTML

```
                <div class="card-img-top"><?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?></div>
                <div class="card-body">
                    <p class="card-text"><?php the_category(', '); ?></p>
                    <h5 class="card-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h5>
                    <p class="card-text excerpt"><?php the_excerpt(); ?></p>
                    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-md btn-rounded border-0 text-white read-more">Read More</button>
                </div>
                </div>
```

CSS

```
.excerpt + p {
  display: none;
}


.excerpt {
  display: block;
}
```

JS

```
const readMoreBtns = document.querySelectorAll('.read-more')

const showMoreHandler = (event) => {
const cardActiveParagraphs = document.querySelectorAll('.excerpt + p')
  
const cardBody = event.target.parentElement
const cardParagraph = cardBody.querySelector('.excerpt + p')
  console.log(cardParagraph)

cardActiveParagraphs.forEach((paragraph) => {
  paragraph.classList.toggle('excerpt')
})
  
}

readMoreBtns.forEach((button) => 
{
button.addEventListener('click', e => showMoreHandler(e));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not toggle what is not in the dom.
When you try to run this line:

```
const cardParagraph = cardBody.querySelector('.excerpt')
cardActiveParagraphs.forEach((paragraph) => {
      paragraph.classList.toggle('excerpt')
    })
```

You will only grab the elements that currently have the excerpt class, but not those that are turned off. A solution would be to add another class, just to grab them:

```
<p class="card-text some-flag-class">the_category</p>
<h5 class="card-title">the_title</h5>
<p class="card-text excerpt some-flag-class">the_excerpt</p>
```

Then, in JS:

```
const cardActiveParagraphs = document.querySelectorAll('.some-flag-class');
cardActiveParagraphs.forEach((paragraph) => {
   paragraph.classList.toggle('excerpt')
})
```

This way, you will always grab both elements, regarding if they are on/off.

Also, you don't need to have a `display: block` and `display: none` class. Enough to have:

```
.excerpt {
  display: none;
}
```

and toggle on/off that class.

Comment: That’s seems a reasonable option now, thanks 

Comment: If this solved your issue, I would appreciate you mark it as the answer

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem with the following js code:

```js
const readMoreBtns = document.querySelectorAll('.read-more')

const showMoreHandler = (event) => {
const cardBody = event.target.parentElement
const cardActiveParagraphs = cardBody.querySelector('.excerpt + p')
  
    if(cardActiveParagraphs.style.display === 'none') {
        cardActiveParagraphs.style.display = 'block';
    }
    else {
        cardActiveParagraphs.style.display = 'none';
    }
}

readMoreBtns.forEach((button) => 
{
button.addEventListener('click', e => showMoreHandler(e));
});
```